# VB.net Creating a class and populating it

Tags: vb.net, list, class, arraylist, populate

Hey all I have this private class code here:

```
Private Class Employee
    Public displayName As String
    Public ntID As String
    Public lastName As String
    Public givenName As String
    Public department As String
    Public eMail As String
End Class
```

That I am trying to add to using this code here:

```
empInfo = New Employee With { _
     .displayName = "", _
     .ntID = "", _
     .lastName = "", _
     .givenName = "", _
     .department = "", _
     .eMail = "" _
   }
}
```

But I am currently getting the error from the above code:

> Value of type 'LDAPemployee.Form1.Employee' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of LDAPemployee.Form1.Employee)'.

Not sure if this is because I converted this from a C# to VB example of what? Any help would be great to solve this issue!

Comment: dont really need all the empty `With` prop setters since they are doing nothing

Comment: empInfo must be a List(Of Employee), not an Employee

Comment: `empInfo.Add(New Employee With {...` is what you're looking for, assuming that `empInfo` is a `List(Of Employee)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just wanna create an instance of a class and set it's values like your title says:

```
    (Dim) x = New Employee

    With x
        .displayName = ""
        .ntID = ""
        .lastName = ""
        .givenName = ""
        .department = ""
        .eMail = ""
    End With
```

assuming empInfo is a list(of) you can then add your new class to that list:

```
empInfo.add(x)
```

please notice that the "with" part in this case is useless  as the variables of the new class allready have the value `""`

i stripped this a bit apart as it is easier to understand if you are new to vb. the short way would be `empInfo.Add(New Employee With {...` as  Andrew Morton said in a comment above